# What should I do if only 1 covariate violate the proportionality assumption in Cox PH?

Tags: r, regression, survival, cox-model

[image]

Can I still use Cox PH model? or I will have to find a non-PH model? What are the available models that can be used here?

**Schoenfeld residuals** (using `survminer::ggcoxdiagnostics`)

[image]

**Scaled Schoenfeld residuals** (using `survival::plot.cox.zph`)

[image]

**Time-transforming option** (Using the `tt` argument)
[image]
I checked whether there is a statistical interaction between `trauma_wi` and time, by introducing `tt(trauma_wi)` into the model. I understand that this is another way to test the proportionality assumption. If this interaction term is not statistically significant, then it follows that the assumption is valid. Which is the case here, where p = 0.3880. Since the assumption is not violated, then there is no need to include this interaction, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on whether you need to estimate a hazard associated with the offending predictor and, if so, whether the violation is large enough to matter in practice.

If you don't care about the hazard associated with the predictor, here a categorical predictor `trauma_wi`, then stratification on that predictor should solve the problem.

If you need to estimate a hazard associated with `trauma_wi`, there are several steps to consider. One is whether you might have omitted some outcome-associated predictors from the model. Sometimes including additional predictors can improve the proportionality for the predictors already included. You seem to have a very large data set, so I'd recommend including many more predictors that you suspect might be associated with outcome if possible, first.

The second possibility is that the violation, even if "statistically significant," isn't large enough to affect the use of your model in practice. For that, you need to see how the magnitudes of the scaled Schoenfeld residuals for the predictor vary with time, depicted as effective coefficient values over time by `plot.cox.zph()`. For example, if you had a coefficient value on the order of $2$ that varied only by $\pm 0.2$ over time, your understanding of the subject matter might suggest that it doesn't matter in practice. It looks like there might be a systematic shift in your residual plots for that predictor from left to right. It's hard to tell how to interpret that, however, as the x-axis is "Observation ID" instead of a function of time, and I can't tell from the axis label whether the residuals are the *scaled* Schoenfeld residuals used to evaluate time dependence that most directly indicate changes in coefficient values over time.

Finally, if the deviation is sufficiently large to matter for your purposes and adding more predictors doesn't improve things, you can model the predictor as having a time-dependent coefficient. You specify a time-dependence function for the coefficient that matches the smoothed path of scaled Schoenfeld residuals over time. Methods for doing so are demonstrated in the [time-dependence vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf) of the R `survival` package.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I edited the post to include the Scaled Schoenfeld residuals (using `survival::plot.cox.zph`). What I understand from your answer ("if you had a coefficient value on the order of 2 that varied only by ±0.2 over time"), is that, if the graph does not fluctuate much, then we could say that the proportionality assumption is valid? I also include the interaction term, by using the time-transformed option (i.e. allowing for the difference in risk by `trauma_wi` to change over time), and found that this term is not statistically significant.

Comment: @HNSKD I'm not sure you used the `tt()` function properly. You need to define a specific `tt()` function within the call to `coxph()`, but your code doesn't show that. See Section 4.2 of the time-dependence vignette. Your scaled residuals are enormous, suggesting that some critical predictors might be missing from your model. A $\beta$ value of 10 corresponds to a hazard ratio of 22000; some of your residuals indicate $\beta$ values of magnitude 20 to 40! Also, what is the reference value for `trauma_wi`? You show coefficients for `Y` and `N`, so what reference level are those with respect to?